# Displaying rich response from Dialogflow in node app

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, richtext

I have successfully connected my node app with my Dialogflow Agent, it is able to detect the correct intents and able to return simple text responses. However, it failed to display rich messages (gif, payload etc). How should I modify my code in a way that it can display my rich messages in the UI?

I tried to change the 'fulfillmentText' to 'fulfillmentMessages', it returned the rich response as [object] in the UI.

Here is my code for app.js and the image of the UI response:

```
const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
// A unique identifier for the given session
const sessionId = uuid.v4();

const { WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended:false
}))

app.use(function (req,res,next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    
    next();
  });

app.post('/send-msg',express.json(), (req,res)=>{
  runSample(req.body.MSG).then(data=>{
    res.send({Reply:data})
  });
});

/**
 * Send a query to the dialogflow agent, and return the query result.
 * @param {string} projectId The project to be used
 */
async function runSample(msg,projectId = 'subjectbotchallenger') {

  // Create a new session
  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    keyFilename:"C:/Users/Chee Keong Bong/Desktop/botui/subjectbotchallenger-2a9c694324b7.json"
  });

  const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

  // The text query request.
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
        text: msg,
        // The language used by the client (en-US)
        languageCode: 'en-US',
      },
    },
  };

  // Send request and log result
  const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  console.log('Detected intent');
  const result = responses[0].queryResult;
  console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
  console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentMessages}`);
  if (result.intent) {
    console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
  } else {
    console.log('  No intent matched.');
  }
  return result.fulfillmentMessages;
}

app.listen(port,()=>{
  console.log("running on port "+port)
})
```

[UI Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzDfe.png)

[Detected Intent - Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSUPX.png)

Comment: Could you share what it the expected rich response you are expecting in the cases you shared the print screens ?

Comment: Can you try to do the JSON.Stringify for the response you are sending back in the API. I think it should solve your problem.